# Hubconnection.Invoke takes several seconds to reach the server

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an issue with a client to server method call take takes several seconds to reach the server.
The code is as simple as this:

```
    this.hubConnection.invoke('OnPendingAlertBadgeCompanyChange', companyId, email)
      .then(_ => {
        Logging.logWithTimestamp(`::: SignalRService => invokeHubForGettingDataForBadgePendingAlerts has been fired. Waiting for data ...`);
        this.gettingDataForBadgePendingAlertsPendingCall = true;
      })
      .catch(reason => {
        this.trowSignalRError(reason)
      });
```

I'm under the impression that the connection may be busy and that the call will be made when it becomes idle.

The hubConnectionState can't tell if it is idle or not:

```
export declare enum HubConnectionState {
    /** The hub connection is disconnected. */
    Disconnected = "Disconnected",
    /** The hub connection is connecting. */
    Connecting = "Connecting",
    /** The hub connection is connected. */
    Connected = "Connected",
    /** The hub connection is disconnecting. */
    Disconnecting = "Disconnecting",
    /** The hub connection is reconnecting. */
    Reconnecting = "Reconnecting"
}
```

Is it something that could happen?

Comment: Is your project running locally or on the server side? If it runs on the server side, are your hubserver and front-end running in the same region?

Comment: front end and server are on the same network

Comment: invoke waits for a response from the hub method. So `.then` wont run until the hub method has completed.